# Differential calculus: $f(x)+f''(x)=-xg(x)f'(x)$, $\forall x \geq 0$ where $g(x) \geq 0, \forall x \geq 0$.

Tags: calculus, functions

> Consider $f$ is a twice differentiable function such that $f(x)+f''(x)=-xg(x)f'(x)$, $\forall x \geq 0$ where $g(x) \geq 0, \forall x \geq 0$.
>
> Prove that for $\forall x \geq0$,
>
> (i)$(f(x))^2+(f'(x))^2$ is a non increasing function.
>
> (ii)$(f(x))^2<3(f(0))^2+4(f'(0))^2$
>
> (iii) $f$ is bounded, that is $|f(x)| \leq a$, for some fixed positive real constant $a$.
>
> (iv) $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ exists.

I could prove part (i).

Let $$h(x)=(f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2$$ $$h'(x)=2f'(x)(f(x)+f''(x))$$ $$=-2xg(x)(f'(x))^2 \leq 0$$ from conditions $x \geq 0$, $g(x) \geq 0, x \geq0$. Hence $h(x)$ is non increasing and part(I) is proved.

Part(ii) attempt
$$3h(0)=3{(f(0))^2+(f'(0))^2}$$ We must prove that this is larger than $$(f(x))^2-(f(0))^2, \forall x\geq0$$ I thought of trying to prove that this is negative.

Let $$p(x)=(f(x))^2$$
$$p'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)$$ $$=2f(x)[\frac{f(x)+f''(x)}{-xg(x)}]$$ I couldn't make further progress.

Part(iii) is a direct consequence of part(ii) and part(iv) is a direct consequence of part(iii).

Answer (score 1):

part (ii).

$$h: x\mapsto (f(x))^2+(f'(x))^2$$
is decreasing at $[0,+\infty), $ thus

$$(\forall x\ge 0)\;\;\; h(x)\le h(0)$$

but

$$(f(x))^2\le (f(x))^2+(f'(x))^2$$
$$\le (f(0))^2+(f'(0))^2$$
$$\le 3(f(0))^2+4(f'(0))^2$$